# CLI command works OK but same entry in/etc/fstab fails. Can anyone offer any assistance?

Tags: fstab

Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Inspiron 3580. The CLI command

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.67/ /media/NAS/storage -o username=Gord,password=Tpocpmoc99,uid=gord,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,vers=1.0,nounix
```

works OK.

But this entry in /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.1.70/Backup /media/NAS/storage -o cifs username=Gord,password=Tpocpmoc99,uid=gord,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,vers=1.0,nounix
```

fails to mount the selected drive. Any info is appreciated.

Comment: You do know the fstab entry and the command you're running are different, yes?  One defines a direct share location, the other doesn't.  Check the syslog for why the fstab mount fails.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Yeah...I do know they are different. The fstab entry is modelled after another fstab entry found on AskUbuntu on StackExchange site. I must be close with my entry but success is elusive.

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem type and options in /etc/fstab are identified by their field positions, rather than using switches like `-o` (or `-t` which you seem to have lost). So:

```
//192.168.1.70/Backup /media/NAS/storage cifs username=Gord,password=Tpocpmoc99,uid=gord,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,vers=1.0,nounix
```

Comment: Thanks steeldriver. That modification brings me back to the selected mounts being visible in 'files' but I am presented with the message."mount:/media/NAS/share:operation permitted for root only". I will rely on the manual cli commands until I master this small miscue in my fstab entries. Thanks for your time. It is appreciated. GordK